# В sql запросе выходит ошибка:Query failed because of: error: column "count" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

всем. Я сделал sql запрос к БД, но выходит эта ошибка:Query failed because of: error: column "count" does not exist. БД использую postgresql. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту задачу
Вот мой sql:

```
   SELECT Students.FirstName, Students.LastName, COUNT (Students.StudentId) AS count 
FROM Students INNER JOIN Exams 
ON Students.StudentId = Exams.StudentId
WHERE Exams.Result < 3
GROUP BY Students.StudentId HAVING count>= 2;
```

Comment: советую не называть названия колонок и таблиц зарезервированными словами

Comment: А еще postgresql не умеет использовать в having алиасы, назначенные в части select. придется писать формулу целиком `having COUNT(Students.StudentId) >= 2`